# brew link new php version error

Tags: php, homebrew

`brew link php70` is giving me the following error:

```
Warning: php@7.0 is keg-only and must be linked with --force
Note that doing so can interfere with building software.
If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

but in `~/.bash_profiles`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/bin
export PATH
```

please tell me how I can solve it.

thanks.

Comment: It should be `~/.bash_profile`, not `~/.bash_profiles`.

Answer (score 0):

Add next lines to your **~/.bash_profile** file:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/sbin:$PATH"
```

Or try adding the next lines in **~/.bashrc** file

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/sbin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue too, running the following command from the terminal fixed it.

Please note that this is for PHP@7.2 and I use ZSH shell:

```
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

So you would run:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Afterwards, close and reopen your terminal for the changes to take affect.